# Freetts: projects works inside the IDE (netbeans and eclipse) but the exported jar give errors

Tags: java, ide, freetts

thank you for reading this.

i m using freetts to make my program speak some text...
While inside the IDE, when i run all the programs, they work fine.(mine and all freetts example programs).

Also the runnable programs (jar) that come with the bin download of freetts, run on terminal fine....     Freetts --> http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetts/files/

Well the exact same programs doesn't work when i export them from the IDE. Tried both netbeans and eclipse to export the programs but i m getting errors.

i m suspecting it has to do with the jar files i include in the projects (jsapi.jar, freetts.jar,freetts-jsapi10.jar). i mean that somehow it may be forbidden to use them this way but maybe i m talking nonsense.

Anyone know what's happening?

i m posting 3 different errors i m getting on terminal **from 3 programs distributions that work fine on IDEs**... sorry for the long post

1.

```
java -jar JSAPIClock.jar 
checkPoint1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jsapiclock.JSAPIClock.createSynthesizer(JSAPIClock.java:49)
    at jsapiclock.JSAPIClock.main(JSAPIClock.java:86)
checkPoint2
checkPoint3
checkPoint4
The time is now, almost half past six, in the evening.
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jsapiclock.JSAPIClock.speak(JSAPIClock.java:74)
    at jsapiclock.Clock.speakTime(Clock.java:233)
    at jsapiclock.Clock.access$000(Clock.java:41)
    at jsapiclock.Clock$ClockThread.run(Clock.java:269)
```

2.notice that Speech.properties file is included in both directories below

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar 

All general Mode JSAPI Synthesizers and Voices:

Using voice: kevin16
No synthesizer created.  This may be the result of any
number of problems.  It's typically due to a missing
"speech.properties" file that should be at either of
these locations: 

user.home    : /home/yiannis
java.home/lib: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib

Another cause of this problem might be corrupt or missing
voice jar files in the freetts lib directory.  This problem
also sometimes arises when the freetts.jar file is corrupt
or missing.  Sorry about that.  Please check for these
various conditions and then try again.
```

3.This is weird actually

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:48)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:55)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:71)
    at java.net.JarURLConnection.getManifest(JarURLConnection.java:217)
    at java.net.JarURLConnection.getMainAttributes(JarURLConnection.java:269)
    at com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager.getDependencyURLs(VoiceManager.java:251)
    at com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager.getDependencyURLs(VoiceManager.java:283)
    at com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager.getVoiceDirectories(VoiceManager.java:173)
    at com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager.getVoices(VoiceManager.java:110)
    at com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral.createEngineList(FreeTTSEngineCentral.java:85)
    at blah2.CustomSpeaker.createSynthesizer(CustomSpeaker.java:34)
    at blah2.FullScreenBox.<init>(FullScreenBox.java:49)
    at blah2.Blah2View.actionPerformed(Blah2View.java:323)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
System property "mbrola.base" is undefined.  Will not use MBROLA voices.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at blah2.CustomSpeaker.createSynthesizer(CustomSpeaker.java:36)
    at blah2.FullScreenBox.<init>(FullScreenBox.java:49)
    at blah2.Blah2View.actionPerformed(Blah2View.java:323)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at blah2.CustomSpeaker.speak(CustomSpeaker.java:61)
    at blah2.Speaker$SpeakerThread.run(Speaker.java:42)
```

Comment: When you distribute the jar, are the Freetts jar files in the classpath when you call java -jar myProgram? I don't see where you're setting the classpath (with the -cw switch) at all

Comment: it is declared in the manifest file... i just found this...http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/java/misc/freetts-line-unavailable-classcastexception-kevinvoicedirectory-error-opening-zipfile.texy   .... check this-->Problem finding dependencies – ZipException` „Error opening ZIP file“.... can you understand whats happening?

Comment: ok i see the problem now... You can't just make a dist of your program cause the libraries are not working correctly. i changed the manifest of my jar (dist) to include the freetts installation lib folder. So the answer is : if you want to distribute your program add the whole freetts in it. (or go the hard way that is mentioned in the link above). i won't bother.... it works.... cheers